# Problems getting spring cloud turbine to connect to Eureka

Tags: spring-cloud

We are trying to get turbine integrated into our application.

I downloaded the 1.o.o sample release (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/turbine/releases/tag/v1.0.0.RELEASE) and built and ran it.  I does not connect to eureka (other services that I have with the same eureka connection settings in application yml connect fine).

Thinking that perhaps I should try the latest version of the turbine smapel (which uses Brixton.SNAPSHOT), I add the spring cloud repos for snapshots to get it to build

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

This release seems to use the 2.0.0 version of turbine which I had to add a manual dependency for.

Still same result and the turbine service does not connect to eureka.

Logs on startup are:

```
2015-06-30 13:17:47.666  INFO 14120 --- [           main] c.l.vipaas.turbine.TurbineApplication    : Starting TurbineApplication v1.0.0.RELEASE on LARMITCH-M-700M with PID 14120 (/Users/larrymitchell/libertas/vipaas/infrastructureservices/turbine/target/turbine.jar started by larrymitchell in /Users/larrymitchell/libertas/vipaas/infrastructureservices/turbine)
2015-06-30 13:17:47.690 DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] c.l.vipaas.turbine.TurbineApplication    : Running with Spring Boot v1.2.4.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.6.RELEASE
2015-06-30 13:17:48.724  INFO 14120 --- [           main] c.l.vipaas.turbine.TurbineApplication    : Started TurbineApplication in 1.559 seconds (JVM running for 3.093)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.4.RELEASE)

2015-06-30 13:17:54.033  INFO 14120 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-06-30 13:17:54.036  INFO 14120 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2015-06-30 13:17:54.257  INFO 14120 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-06-30 13:17:57.154  WARN 14120 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2015-06-30 13:17:57.154  INFO 14120 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2015-06-30 13:17:57.171  INFO 14120 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@63a5621d
2015-06-30 13:18:01.722  WARN 14120 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2015-06-30 13:18:01.723  INFO 14120 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2015-06-30 13:18:02.273  INFO 14120 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-06-30 13:18:02.273  INFO 14120 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2015-06-30 13:18:02.285  INFO 14120 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/manage]        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-06-30 13:18:02.677  INFO 14120 --- [           main] i.reactivex.netty.server.AbstractServer  : Rx server started at port: 8989
2015-06-30 13:18:03.070  INFO 14120 --- [           main] c.l.vipaas.turbine.TurbineApplication    : Started TurbineApplication in 16.006 seconds (JVM running for 17.437
```

When I look at Eureka, I can not see any checkins for Turbine whereas I see checkins for the other services

Also I set the netflix discovery log level to DEBUG.

Comment: any errors in logs? Do you have eureka set up on localhost with default port?

Comment: logs are quiet.  No exceptions or errors.  I will add what is there to the post.  I have exactly the same connectivity to eureka that my other services have.  They connect and turbine does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I moved the eureka settings to bootstrap and it started to connect to eureka.  If the settings are in the application.yml only then it does not attempt to connect.   Probably some override deep underneath.

Also a caveat on the connectivity.  If you want to get the management side coming up in a console like the spring cloud console (see https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-cloud-dashboard) then you need to register the management port and not server.port.